# Create a file with limited file size

Tags: java, files

I have written a **server(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server)** - client - java program.

With this program I can send a text from my android-smartphone to my server saving it to the `receivedData` file.

The program is running under a user which has no shell assigned and no access to sensitive data or programs by default.

The only security issue I can think of is running out of memory due to a tons of gigabyte `receivedData` file which has no size check. Or, of course a DoS attack but I do not think my server is that important...

The program is just for learning purposes and shall not be used by any clients/hackers(of course ;)) but you never now..

So, can anyone tell me if it is possible to directly create a file `receivedData` with a limited file size. At the moment it reaches the file size it should deny `receivedData` preventing it from causing an OOM.

If not I will need to implement that into the java program...

Comment: Altough "The program is just for learning purposes and shall not be used by any clients/hackers", if I were you I'd still implement this in the program for portability

Comment: Note that an OOM is a different thing - it's Out of Memory in the RAM sense.  Size of files created by the processes need not necessarily affect the memory being used by it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways this can be done:

- using the `ulimit` shell utility, or using the `setrlimit` system call (which is what `ulimit` calls in turn).
- using filesystem quotas, and a special user for the server process, will restrict the **total** usage of that user

---

#### `ulimit`/`setrlimit`

From [`man 2 setrlimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man2/setrlimit.2.html):

```
RLIMIT_FSIZE
      The maximum size of files that the process may create.  Attempts
      to extend a file beyond this  limit  result  in  delivery  of  a
      SIGXFSZ  signal.   By default, this signal terminates a process,
      but a process can catch this signal instead, in which  case  the
      relevant  system  call  (e.g., write(2), truncate(2)) fails with
      the error EFBIG.
```

I'm not sure how one could invoke the `setrlimit` function from Java, but [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/invoke-syscalls-from-java) might help. Alternatively, wrap the Java server in a script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
ulimit -f 1073741824   # 1GB
java ....
```

---

#### Filesystem Quotas:

I'm assuming an ext4 filesystem, I'm unsure about others. First, we need to enable quota on the filesystem. Edit `/etc/fstab`, and add `usrquota` to the mount options of the appropriate partition. If we're doing this for `/`, for example, the final entry would look something like:

```
UUID=... /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrquota 0       1
```

Then enable it after restarting:

```
sudo quotaon /
```

I'll assume your server is run as a different user (say `restricted_user`). If not, create one if you don't want your normal processes to be affected.

Then do:

```
sudo edquota restricted_user
```

Which will open an editor.

```
Disk quotas for user restricted_user (uid 1001):
  Filesystem                   blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
  /dev/sdd1                   1087940    943718   1048576       9956        0        0
```

Set the soft and hard limits to the appropriate values (they're  1024-byte blocks, so divide your limit by 1024). Save and quit.

Then the user will not be able to exceed a *total* of 1G usage on that filesystem, counting all files owned by them.

---

Naturally, you should still check the size in your server program.

Comment: +1: Extremely good answer (said without flattery). I've edited the titles as them seemed so big. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Helio no, that's fine. But I still prefer proper header tags, so I edit them to use `h3` tags (`###` in markdown).

Comment: Ok, now it's better.

Comment: Why don't i have to run `sudo quotacheck` in your solution as recommended in [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/) tutorial? Is it automatically started when i reboot? How can i do a `quotacheck` on the root system when it is mounted?

Comment: @Mike the `quotacheck` command is a reporting tool. It doesn't enforce anything. Whether you run it or not is entirely up to you

Comment: Ok and am I right saying that `errors=remount-ro,quota 0` is the equivalent of `errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota 0`?

Comment: @Mike but that did remind me, I made a mistake in the mount options. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike no, it was `usrquota`, not just `quota`. The answer doesn't use group quotas.

Comment: Yeah yeah..., i understand that but instead of writing usrquota,grpquota i could only write quota if i also want to monitor groups?! Yeah as you see that was my second question because in no tutorial they did use just quota. But i tried with `errors=remount-ro,quota` and it works. But now i strongly believe that I am monitoring groups as well.

Comment: @Mike that's because `quota` is same as `usrquota` (see [`man ext4`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html): "The usrquota (same as quota) mount option enables user quota
              support on the filesystem.".

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE:

The answer by muru is perfect for file size, I'm here giving a solution how to size a directory itself, not just a file.

---

There is no such thing direct since filesystem deal with a folder as file of files and its limit is the whole filesystem itself.

So as a workaround for your problem you can do a trick creating a virtual filesystem and mount it on a specific (empty) directory.

create the mount point of the virtual file system to mount on (~/test for me)

```
mkdir ~/test
```

create a file full of /dev/zero, large enough to the maximum size you want to reserve for the virtual filesystem  (i'm doing here for 1MB)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1024 count=0 seek=1024
```

format this file with an ext4 filesystem

```
 mke2fs test.img
```

mount the newly formatted disk space in the directory you've created as mount point

```
mount -o loop test.img ~/test
```

Then use this directory

Comment: It certainly is possible (see the answers by @muru and @the_Seppi).  If it's only one file, however, it would be easier to track total file-size in Java and give a friendly error-message if the limit is reached.

Comment: @david I answered him for sizing a folder not just a file, read my answer again. The original post was about that, not just limiting a file itself

Comment: I like your solution. I tried it and it works. Also, any owner or permission changes made to the mounting directory e.g. /mnt/ are affecting the file ( in your case `test.img`) and not the directory. Now I will spend some time on murus solution! ;)

Comment: @Mike nice to hear that

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's safest to check the file size inside the java program.

You can append to any file you have write access to, as long as there is enough space in the partition, so you cannot limit a file's size directly.

The only thing I can think of is to create a partition only for this file, so the file size will be limited to the partition's size. Also, if you'd format the partition as FAT32, the file could have a maximum size of 4 GiB.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell if your application would OOM or not.

Usually, you would read a manageable chunk of data (say 1MB) from the socket and write that chunk of data directly to a file. That way, you'd never store more than the temporary chunk in memory at any one time.

Typically this looks like:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("receivedData");

InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer);
};
```

You could then add a counter to the while loop to count how many bytes have been written to the file and terminate the socket should it go over a predetermined amount or is getting close to consuming all available disk space.